# assigning BindingSources with DataMembers shows 'DataMember property 'Unit:UnitGroup' cannot be found on the DataSource.'

Tags: c#, data-binding, dataset, relationship, bindingsource

I have a scenario where I have 3 tables for example

if I have Unit table that is linked to two other tables ( UnitGroup & UnitGroupDetail )

how to create their BindingSources  correctly

I write an example of what I'm trying to do. I made everything clear inside it

please help me

Here is the code :

```
    private BindingSource _mainBs;
    private BindingSource _unitGroupBs;
    private BindingSource _unitGroupDetailBs;

    private BindingSource _unitUnitGroupBs;
    private BindingSource _unitUnitGroupDetail;

    private static DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet("UnitGroup");

        // Create unit table that contains units informations 
        var unit = new DataTable("Unit");
        unit.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitID", typeof(int)));
        unit.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitName", typeof(string)));
        dataSet.Tables.Add(unit);

        // Create Unit group 
        var unitGroup = new DataTable("UnitGroup");
        unitGroup.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GroupID", typeof(int)));
        unitGroup.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("GroupName", typeof(string)));
        unitGroup.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BaseUnitID", typeof(int)));
        dataSet.Tables.Add(unitGroup);
        // Adding the relation between UnitGroup table and Unit table

        var unitGroupDetail = new DataTable("UnitGroupDetail");
        unitGroupDetail.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitGroupDetailID", typeof(int)));
        unitGroupDetail.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitGroupID", typeof(int)));
        unitGroupDetail.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitID", typeof(int)));
        unitGroupDetail.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ConversionRate", typeof(decimal)));
        dataSet.Tables.Add(unitGroupDetail);

        // Relation Name : Unit:UnitGroup
        dataSet.Relations.Add("Unit:UnitGroup",unit.Columns["UnitID"], unitGroup.Columns["BaseUnitID"]);
        // Relation Name : UnitGroup:UnitGroupDetail
        dataSet.Relations.Add("UnitGroup:UnitGroupDetail",unitGroup.Columns["GroupID"], unitGroupDetail.Columns["UnitGroupID"]);
        // Relation Name : Unit:UnitGroupDetail
        dataSet.Relations.Add("Unit:UnitGroupDetail",unit.Columns["UnitID"], unitGroupDetail.Columns["UnitID"]);

        return dataSet;
    }


    private void PrepareBindingSources()
    {
        _mainBs = new BindingSource(GetDataSet(), string.Empty);

        _unitGroupBs = new BindingSource(_mainBs, "UnitGroup");

        _unitGroupDetailBs = new BindingSource(_unitGroupBs, "UnitGroup:UnitGroupDetail");

        _unitUnitGroupBs = new BindingSource(_unitGroupBs, "Unit:UnitGroup");

        _unitUnitGroupDetail = new BindingSource(_unitGroupDetailBs, "Unit:UnitGroupDetail");

    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrepareBindingSources();
    }
```

When I run the code it says 
System.ArgumentException: 'DataMember property 'Unit:UnitGroup' cannot be found on the DataSource.'

Comment: You should rewrite this question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are not likely to get any responses to your question when you have all your code in a rar file. Aside from security concerns, if the link were to break, other users seeing this question in the future would not be able to see your example.

Comment: Thanks I edited my question I hope this would be fine